# Accessing Isolated Scope of Sibling resulted from same angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angularjs directive which will produce a multi select drop down with slightly complicated template.  The directives are having an isolated scope. Based on the dropdown click a variable named  `open` in the dropdown is toggling and visibility is adjusted. currenly he dropdown is closing only when DOM is clicked. But if user clicking two  dropdowns one after the other, both remains open. We can close, the sibling dropdown, by accessing its scope and setting the value for `open`. **How can I access the isolated scope of sibling originated from the same directive ?**

```
var directiveModule = angular.module('angular-drp-multiselect', []);
directiveModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselect', ['$filter', '$document', '$compile', '$parse',
function ($filter, $document, $compile, $parse) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            selectedModel: '=',
            options: '=',
            extraSettings: '=',
            events: '=',
            searchFilter: '=?',
            translationTexts: '=',
            groupBy: '@'                
        },
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            var checkboxes = attrs.checkboxes ? true : false;
            var groups = attrs.groupBy ? true : false;

            var template = '<div class="multiselect-parent btn-group dropdown-multiselect btn-block ">';
            template += '<button type="button" ng-disabled="getDisableStatus()" class="dropdown-toggle btn-block btn-leftAlign" ng-class="settings.buttonClasses" ng-click="HideAllOpenDropDowns();toggleDropdown($event)" ng-attr-title="{{getButtonTitle()}}">{{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>';
            template += '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" ng-data="{{open}}"  ng-style="{display: open ? \'block\' : \'none\', height : settings.scrollable ? settings.scrollableHeight : \'auto\' }" style="overflow: scroll" >';
            template += '<li ng-hide="!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0"><a data-ng-click="selectAll()">  {{texts.checkAll}}</a>';
           .....
            element.html(template);
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var $dropdownTrigger = $element.children()[0];

            $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
            //here I need to access all siblings(generated from the same directive) scope , to control the visibility, by setting value for $scope.open
            //I tried the following things
            --------------------------------------
            //Attempt 1- not working
            angular.forEach(angular.element($element.parent().parent().children()), function (value, key) {
                var x = angular.element(value).scope();
                    x.open = false;
                     //x.$apply(function () {
                        // x.open = false;
                     //});
                     }
            //Attempt  2- not working
            angular.forEach(angular.element($(".multiselect-parent")), function (value, key) {

                var menuElem = angular.element(value);
                var menuElemScope = menuElem.scope();
                menuElemScope.$apply(function () {
                    menuElemScope.open = false;
                });
            });


            --------------------------------------
              $scope.open = !$scope.open;
            };
            ...
            ...
```

The html is

```
<div ng-app="multiSelectApp">
        <div ng-controller="MultiSelect">

        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
            extra-settings="DropDownSettings1" >
        </div>

        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
            extra-settings="DropDownSettings2" >
        </div>

        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
            extra-settings="DropDownSettings3" >
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find searching for DOM elements to affect a sibling directive not the angular way.

You can do something like this

```
link: function(element, attrs){
    ....
    $rootScope.$on('openChanged', function(event, open){
        scope.isOpen = open;
    });
    scope.toggleOpen = function(){
        var wasOpen = scope.isOpen;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openChanged', false);
        scope.isOpen = !wasOpen;
    }
```

However for a big app I would suggest to implement a service for communication instead of using `$rootScope`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/2bp2pqav/) with an example

**UPDATE**
Regarding service implementation.
My advise is not to reinvent the wheel and use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-event-emitter.

However, there is a quick solution to implement smth like

```
.factory('broadcastService', function () {
    var handlers = {};
    this.on = function (eventName, callback) {
        var callbacks = handlers[eventName];
        if (!callbacks) {
            handlers[eventName] = callbacks = [];
        }
        if (typeof callback === 'function' && callbacks.indexOf(callback) < 0) {
            callbacks.push(callback);
        }
    };
    this.broadcast = function (eventName, args) {
        var callbacks = handlers[eventName];
        if (callbacks) {
            callbacks.map(function (handler) {
                try {
                    handler({
                        name: eventName
                    }, args);
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.error(ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Really great.. Thanks a lot.. Its working like a charm.. Could you please give some insight on how this can be converted as a service?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. I am a newbie to angular. I am  looking into it, and trying to understand the same..